# NOT NULL constraint failed:orders_order.user_id

Tags: python, django, web, django-models, django-views

I am new to django and i am building an ecommerce website.
When i try to make a new order in my website i got this error:
NOT NULL constraint failed:orders_order.user_id

each user can have multiple orders and i want to show the orders in the users profile but i am having problem with placing orders

models.py

```
class Order(models.Model):
user = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
address = models.CharField(max_length=250)
postal_code = models.CharField(max_length=11)
city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
paid = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Meta:
    ordering = ('-created',)

def __str__(self):
    return f'Order {self.id}'

def get_total_cost(self):
    return sum(item.get_cost() for item in self.items.all())


class OrderItem(models.Model):
order = models.ForeignKey(Order, related_name='items', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

product = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name='order_items', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.id)

def get_cost(self):
    return self.price * self.quantity
```

forms.py

```
class OrderCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Order
    fields = ['address', 'postal_code', 'city']
```

views.py

```
def order_create(request):
cart = Cart(request)
if request.method == 'POST':
    user = request.user
    form = OrderCreateForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        order = form.save()
        for item in cart:
            OrderItem.objects.create(order=order, product=item['product'], price=item['price'],
                                     quantity=item['quantity'])
        context = {
            'order': order,
        }
        # clear the cart
        cart.clear()
        return render(request, 'order/created.html', context)
else:
    form = OrderCreateForm()
context = {'cart': cart,
           'form': form,
           }
return render(request, 'order/create.html', context)
```

template

```
{% extends 'shared/_MainLayout.html' %}

{% block content %}
<h1>Checkout</h1>

<div class="order-info">
    <h3>Your order</h3>
    <ul>
        {% for item in cart %}
            <li>
                {{ item.quantity }}x {{ item.product.name }}
                <span>${{ item.total_price }}</span>
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    <p>Total: ${{ cart.get_total_price }}</p>
</div>

<form method="post" class="order-form">
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <p><input type="submit" value="Place order"></p>
    {% csrf_token %}
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: You assign `user` in `views.py` but never use it. Should it be passed to `OrderCreateForm`?

Comment: @MadCowDisease how can i pass it to the form?

Comment: It's easier said than done apparently, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53955850/pass-variable-from-view-to-form-django could solve your issue

Comment: Alternatively try passing user to the form save function:
`order = form.save(user=user)`

Comment: @MadCowDisease i got this error i think that is not working       save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'user'

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method 
scroll down to the note, the implementation is different but the idea is the same. You set the user before saving the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem solved:
in views.py it should be like this:

```
order = form.save(commit=False)
order.user = request.user
order.save()
```

Comment: Please read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to improve your answers?

Answer (score 0):

OrderCreateForm is used to create an order but you didn't specify user field so you should add user object to Order before saving it at views.py
when you call form.save() it tries to create Order object but there is no user for this order and that's why you get NOT NULL constraint failed:orders_order.user_id

Comment: can you explain more specific?

Comment: so you have this line of code in your views.py: order = form.save() then you need to add request.user to order like this: order.user = request.user and then order.save() try add these and if you have any problem just let me know